# How to rewrite if else statement into switch statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I understand how if else statements work and switch statements but I don't understand how you rewrite this code into a switch statement (C++), whatever I think is right turns out to be errors..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

enum Day { MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY
};

Day workDay;

workDay = MONDAY;

if (workDay == MONDAY)
{

cout << "Monday \n";
}

else if (workDay == TUESDAY)
{

cout << "Tuesday \n";
}

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? And please format your code properly.

Comment: If you were helping someone solve this, what would you want to know?

Comment: *whatever I think is right turns out to be errors* - where's the attempt? Where are the errors?

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and please show us the code that does not work including the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted, it's not clear what you're expecting.

Also, since you set workDay to MONDAY, it will always print Monday, but it's only test code...

However, in the spirit if trying to be helpful, I think you're after something like this:

```
switch (workDay)
{
    case MONDAY: cout << "Monday \n"; break;
    case TUESDAY: cout << "Tuesday \n"; break;
    default: cout << "Not a supported day \n"; break;
}
```

You can add other cases as you need. I put in a default, because it's generally a good idea.